# Batch, read file and copy file name like

Tags: batch-file

I get stuck on a basic problem :(

I want to read a txt file from a batch file, copy files name like found in the file to a new directory

Exemple : 
- My src folder contains Microsoft KB (arround 300 files) with name Like "Windows 6.1-KBxxxxx.msu" 
- My file [KB.Txt] is look like : 
KB320000 
KB320001 
- dst folder is empty

...
So I want to copy only KB in my KB.txt from src to dst

My batch look like :

```
set src=%~dp0\src
set dst=%~dp0\dst
set file=%~dp0KB.txt

for /f "delims=" %%i in (%file%) do (
xcopy "%src%\%%i" "%dst%\%%i" /i /z /y /s
)
```

This do not work because the script only try to copy with exact name.
I have tested with wildcards with no success... What I have done wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: I think `COPY` supports wildcards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set src=%~dp0\src
set dst=%~dp0\dst
set file=%~dp0KB.txt

for /f "delims=" %%i in (%file%) do (
   copy /y  "%src%\*%%i*" "%dst%\" 
)
```

copy command supports wildcards so enclosing `%%i` with asterisks should work.
Using `XCOPY` for files (the command is designed for folders) is a bad idea as it will prompt if you want to create a destination directory.